# How to hoist Conduit of STT

Tags: haskell, monad-transformers, conduit, st-monad

I've been trying to write an implementation of the function:

```
foo :: Monad m => ConduitM i o (forall s. STT s m) r -> ConduitM i o m r
```

But I've been failing at every turn with the error:

```
Couldn't match type because variable `s` would escape its scope.
```

I'm now suspicious that implementing this function is impossible.

```
threadSTT :: Monad m
       => (forall a. (forall s. STT s m a) -> m a)
       -> ConduitM i o (forall s. STT s m) r
       -> ConduitM i o m r
threadSTT runM (ConduitM c0) =
    ConduitM $ \rest ->
        let go (Done r) = rest r
            go (PipeM mp) = PipeM $ do
                r <- runM mp -- ERROR
                return $ go r
            go (Leftover p i) = Leftover (go p) i
            go (NeedInput x y) = NeedInput (go . x) (go . y)
            go (HaveOutput p f o) = HaveOutput (go p) (runM f) o -- ERROR
         in go (c0 Done)

foo :: Monad m => ConduitM i o (forall s. STT s m) r -> ConduitM i o m r
foo = threadSTT STT.runST
```

Can anyone speak to this?  I'd really love it to work, but if I can't then I need abandon use of `Data.Array.ST` for writing my conduits.

Comment: The type `ConduitM i o (forall s. STT s m) r -> ConduitM i o m r` is what is called an impredictive type, because there is a `forall` inside of a type constructor (`ConduitM` in this case). Type inference fails utterly and horrifically (for theoretical and practical reasons) in the presence of impredictive types. You can get around this by annotating *everything* with a type signature, or defining a newtype for your quantified type: `newtype X m = X (forall s . STT s m)` and then `foo :: ConduitM i o (X m) r -> ...`.

Comment: Why not just implement `foo :: ConduitM i o (STT s m) r -> ConduitM i o m r` instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you have reinvented the `MFunctor` instance of `ConduitM`. You may check the [source code](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/conduit-1.2.6.1/docs/src/Data-Conduit-Internal-Conduit.html#line-140).

By the author of conduit package, [monad hoist in this style gives surprising results when you try to unwrap a monad with side effect](https://github.com/snoyberg/conduit/wiki/Dealing-with-monad-transformers). In you case `runST` will be called multiple times so the state is thrown every time the conduit produces an item.

You'd better lift every other conduit on the line from `Conduit i o m r` to `Conduit i o (STT s m) r` and call `runST` on the result. It's as easy as `transPipe lift`.